# How to return an object from a recursed function?

Tags: vb.net, recursion, asp.net-3.5

I'm needing to go through all the controls on a page, looking for a specific one.  We've got a bunch of user controls, a masterpage, content panel, &c.

The basic idea is simple, but once I find the control I want, say five 'layers' in, the control is returned only one level.

I know I can do something cheesy like having a private variable and assigning the control to that down in the rabbit hole, but I figure there must be a more official method of doing this.

Also, is this what is called tail recursion?

We're using the 3.5 framework.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim c As Control = getNamedControl(Page, "tb")
End Sub


Private Function getNamedControl(ByVal root As Control, ByVal theTarget As String) As Control
    If root.Controls.Count < 1 Then
        If Not IsNothing(root.ID) Then
            If root.ID = theTarget Then
                Return root
            End If
        End If
    Else
        For Each c As Control In root.Controls
            If c.ID = theTarget Then
                Return c
            Else
                getNamedControl(c, theTarget)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Module WebControlExtensions
    ' Can be used to find controls recursively that won't be found via Page.FindControl 
    ' because they are nested in other NamingContainers 
    ' Example: Dim ctrl = Page.FindControlRecursive("tb") '
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function FindControlRecursive(ByVal rootControl As Web.UI.Control, ByVal controlID As String) As Web.UI.Control
        If rootControl.ID = controlID Then
            Return rootControl
        End If

        For Each controlToSearch As Web.UI.Control In rootControl.Controls
            Dim controlToReturn As Web.UI.Control = FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, controlID)
            If controlToReturn IsNot Nothing Then
                Return controlToReturn
            End If
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Module
```

The function will immediately return the control when it was found.

> We've got a bunch of user controls, a masterpage, content panel...

Are you sure that it's a good idea to use a recursive function to find your controls? Especially if you use UserControls with the same ID in pages of the MasterPage's ContentPages, you would probably find the wrong control. This is very error-prone.

Besides you are hard-wiring your UserControls with their pages with their MasterPage, what is the opposite of encapsulation and reusability.

Comment: I'm just getting some coffee down and my solution is at the office, so I can't digest this yet.  However, thank you for the reply and even more for the thoughtful question about whether this is even the best approach to this problem.  I feel as though I'm always going to have more to learn - the design methodologies and considerations are limitless versus the language and techniques which, while extensive, are at some point finite.

Comment: I must admit that i've never needed to use my own recursive function at all. You should first learn how controls are nested in each other, learn what are the [NamingContainers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) of controls. Then you know how to get a reference to the control in the correct way(directly). Then learn [how UserControls should communicate with their pages(and vice-versa)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5510150/284240), pages with their masterpage and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
    If c.ID = theTarget Then
        Return c
    Else
        getNamedControl(c, theTarget)
    End If
```

becomes:

```
    If c.ID = theTarget Then
        Return c
    Else
        Dim d as Control
        d = getNamedControl(c, theTarget)
        If Not IsNothing(d) Then
           return d
        End If
    End If
```

Then just before ending the function:

```
  return Null
```

EDIT:

assuming the return value is examined, this isn't tail recursion.

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call
search for "foo3"